# Spring reactive WebSession with JDBC (or R2DBC)

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I'm trying to migrate my Servlet-based application to Webflux and got stuck with session management. I've been using Spring session with Jdbc implementation (backed by PostgreSQL) for a while and my config looks like this:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableSpringHttpSession
    public static class SessionConfig {

        @Bean
        public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
            return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        }
    }
```

Now, as I understood [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#websession) correctly, servlet-based `HttpSession` has been replaced with `WebSession` and I need to provide configuration like the following:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableSpringWebSession
    public class SessionConfig {

        @Bean
        public ReactiveSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
            return ???
        }
    }
```

But I could not find any support for relational databases as there are only 2 implementations of `org.springframework.session.ReactiveSessionRepository` (from `"org.springframework.session:spring-session-core:2.2.2.RELEASE"`):

- Basic one - `ReactiveMapSessionRepository`
- Redis-based one - `ReactiveRedisSessionRepository`

but unfortunately, they do not satisfy my requirement.

I also could not find any notes neither for `"org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc"` support for `WebSessions`, nor for new R2DBC.

---

**Is it possible to back `WebSessions` by relational database (e.g. Postgres) and if it is, how can I achieve this (which implementation should I use)?** I know there are some issues with non-blocking operations support for relational databases but I wonder if I missed something and it's still possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Spring Session does not provide a JDBC implementation of `ReactiveSessionRepository`, since JDBC is of a blocking nature.

When building a reactive web application, currently only Redis and MongoDB can be auto-configured.

If it's necessary for you to use JDBC with WebFlux, it is possible to back `WebSession` by relational database, by configuring a custom implementation of `ReactiveSessionRepository`.

First, make sure you consider whether WebFlux is a good fit for your use case.
From the [Spring Framework documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-framework-choice):

> If you have blocking persistence APIs (JPA, JDBC), or networking APIs to use, then Spring MVC is the best choice for common architectures at least. It is technically feasible with both Reactor and RxJava to perform blocking calls on a separate thread but you wouldn’t be making the most of a non-blocking web stack.

If you do implement a custom `ReactiveSessionRepository`, you may find [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#custom-sessionrepository) of the Spring Session docs useful.

Comment: if you move from a non-reactive spring security world, to the reactive one, you would _expect_ remember me to work kind of in the same manner. We spent a lot of time moving to reactive stack only to find out that remember-me is not supported for jdbc. And I get the reasonings, but this should be stipulated in the spring security documentation much, much more cleaner; as it's missing completely now.